# Problem with SQLiteConnection in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, .net-3.5, system.data.sqlite

I am developing a C# WPF project with an embedded SQLite Database. I have used SQLite before without problems but for some reason when I call:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection("my connection string");
```

However, when this code executes it displays the error

> XamlParserException was unhandled
>   Cannot create instance of MainWindow.xaml defined in assembly 'MyProject', Version=1.0.0.0...
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Error in markup file 'MainWindow.xaml' Line 1 position 9.

At this position is the following code in the XAML file

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"  x:Class="MySQLBackup.MainWindow"
```

I have set the project to be .Net Framework 3.5 so I do not understandw why I am getting this error and why it is saying it is an error in the XAML when it calls the SQLiteConnection in the class file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
As requested below is the stacktrace and inner exception

Inner Exception

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   configuration section userSettings/Gui.Properties.Settings.
>   (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MySQLBackup.vshost.exe_Url_5ar2cuyxbdeg3v0bx5aak4mgjx2jmsbn\1.0.0.0\user.config
>   line 17)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
>   schemaErrors)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object
>   sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)

Stacktrace

> at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object
>   sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(InternalConfigEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String
>   configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(String
>   sectionName, Boolean isUserScoped)    at
>   System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext
>   context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider
>   provider)    at
>   System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String
>   propertyName)    at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   MySQLBackup.Properties.Settings.get_app_dbPassword() in
>   c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\MySQLBackup\MySQLBackup\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs:line
>   43    at MySQLBackup.SqlDatabaseWork..ctor() in
>   c:\users\chris\documents\visual studio
>
> 2010\Projects\MySQLBackup\MySQLBackup\Logic\SqlDatabaseWork.cs:line 25

Comment: can you show the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with SQLite... What is the InnerException of the XamlParseException?

Comment: I've put the exception and stack trace as an update in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve it. I think it was something to do with the user.config file that is created by the application. I deleted the user.config and then told visual studio to rebuild and then it seemed to work.

Thanks for your help